# Spring + Thymeleaf pagination

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I try to build simple forum and i have problem with pagination in front end.
I build page where got all my topics, for example there is 50, so choose 10 topics for every page so should get 5 pages, where topics is 150, there should be 15 pages. Im cannot resolve how to hide this 1, 2, 3, 4, to 15 pages which are display below list. I want to display just number 1, current page and last number page(15). This code below is good for few pages, but if you have hundreds or more then this code will display you hundreds numbers of page.

```
<div th:if = "${totalPages > 1}">
    <div class = "row col-sm-10">
        <div class = "col-sm-2">
            Total topics: [[${totalElements}]]
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-1">
                <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, totalPages)}">
                    <a th:if="${currentPage != i}" th:href="@{'/topic/page/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage != i}">[[${i}]]</span>  &nbsp; &nbsp;
                </span>
        </div>

        <div class = "col-sm-1">
            <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/topic/page/' + ${currentPage + 1}}">Next</a>
            <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Next</span>
        </div>

        <div class = "col-sm-1">
            <a th:if="${currentPage > 1}" th:href="@{'/topic/page/' + ${currentPage - 1}}">Previous</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <a th:if="${currentPage < totalPages}" th:href="@{'/topic/page/' + ${totalPages}}">Last</a>
            <span th:unless="${currentPage < totalPages}">Last</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Someone can help me with this? Im weak in front end and not to much understand how to resolve it ;s

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is what I did to solve it.
I pass to my template an array with the length equals to the number of pages + the current page to be displayed:

```
model.addAttribute("pages", new int[pageAllGuests.getTotalPages()]);
model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
```

then on my HTML page I make some tests to display or not the link to the page:

```
<ul class="pager">
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage == 0}">
                        <li><a title="First Page"
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=0,keyword=${keyword})}"
                            >&laquo;</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a title="Previous Page"
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${currentPage-1},keyword=${keyword})}"
                            >&lsaquo;</a>
                        </li>
                        <li th:if="${currentPage>3}">
                            <a title="Previous Pages" 
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${currentPage-3},keyword=${keyword})}"
                            >...</a>
                        </li>
                    </span>
                    <li th:each="page,i:${pages}" th:class="${i.index==currentPage?'active':''}"  th:if="${i.index > currentPage-4 AND i.index < currentPage+4}" >
                        <a 
                        th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${i.index},keyword=${keyword})}"
                        th:text="${i.index+1}"> </a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <span th:unless="${currentPage == pages.length-1 || pages.length == 0}" >
                        <li th:if="${currentPage+4<pages.length}">
                            <a title="Next Pages" 
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${currentPage+5},keyword=${keyword})}"
                            >...</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a title="Next Page"
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${currentPage+1},keyword=${keyword})}"
                            >&rsaquo;</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a 
                            th:href="@{admin(status=${status}, jobdescription=${jobdescription},page=${pages.length-1},keyword=${keyword})}"
                            title="Last Page">&raquo;</a>
                        </li>
                    </span>
                </ul>
```

below is a picture of the result

[pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB1br.png)

This code may probably be improved but at least it is easy to read and understand.
You will need to clean the code (parameters in href) and adapt it to your case.